# Nesting functions within a Dom event

Tags: javascript

I need to run an onmousedown function (to change the color of a button) when it is clicked.  I need it to run within another function - when the button clicked.  How would I do this I am a little confused?

```
myPunk.play = function() {
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0;i <buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        var pushIt = this.id;
        console.log(this.id);
        function changeColor(){

        }
        var workIt = soundManager.createSound({
        url: "/sounds/" + pushIt +".wav"
    })
workIt.play()
})
}

}
myPunk.play()
```

Comment: Your mostly confusing yourself. Why do you ***need it to run within another function***? What exactly are you trying to do? (your code looks like it's too complicated for no good reason)

Comment: It is a daft punk soundboard that works fine.   What I wan to do is change the color of the input when the user presses on one of the buttons.  Does this make sense?

Comment: So you want to change the background-color of ALL `<input>` elements whenever ANY `<input>` element is clicked? (Side-note: The part about daft-punk is entertaining, but irrelevant :-) Please read [ask] to learn how to ask good, complete questions)

Comment: Yes I want all input values to change colour - when they are clicked (onmousedown) and then return to their original color on mouseup

Comment: 1. click & mousedown/up are not the same. If you want to react to the latter, why are you listening to the former? 2. setup a sample code (MCVE, as I advised above) in order to get a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, edited the answer, to include the on mouseup and mousedown events instead of the click. You should be looking for something like this.

```
   myPunk.play = function() {
        function changeColor(button, color){
            button.style.background = color;
        }

        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            buttons[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
                changeColor(this, "#FF0000");
                var pushIt = this.id;
                var workIt = soundManager.createSound({
                    url: "/sounds/" + pushIt +".wav"
                })
                workIt.play()
            });

            buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
                changeColor(this, "");
            });
        }
    }
    myPunk.play()
```

Comment: Using javascript dom events I want to be able to change the color of my input buttons , so that when the user clicks on a button it changes color briefly before returning to it's original color.

Comment: When should it return to it's original color? After a set amount of time or on mouseup?

Comment: Like Amit mentions above mouseup and mousedown are separate events from click, but the edited code above should do the trick.

Comment: great it works thanks - It makes sense how it all works :)